# cannot create project using composer in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have downloaded composer and installed the composer and when i run the composer command it confirms that composer has installed. But when try to create the project it shows the following error.

[image]

Comment: I belive you have copied --prefer-dist command. Type it manually.the command contains invalid character may be different unicode

Comment: nope still not working

Comment: verify you composer.json file

Comment: where is it located?

Comment: in project root directory

Comment: add

 "repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.org" }, { "packagist": false } ] 
to your composer.json situated in AppData\Roaming

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel [PATH]
```

I think it helps. I got the same problem before and problem was in order of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the version for a more specific installation, try something like this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel [PATH] 5.3.10
```

Bests!